# How do I get a LinkedIn request token?

Tags: post, oauth, linkedin-api

Hey I'm trying to use LinkedIn's OAuth in PHP. I'm stuck at the first step of getting a request token. All I know is you post some values to their server and get your token back. So i post the documented args to 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken' and I get slapped with a 400 error.

here's the request:

```
$postArr = array();
//$postArr["oauth_callback"] = ""; idk they said this was optional...
$postArr["oauth_consumer_key"] = "ForBritishEyesOnly"; //is this the application secret key or the api key?
$postArr["oauth_nonce"] = "UltraRandomNonceFTW";
$postArr["oauth_timestamp"] = time();
$postArr["oauth_signature_method"] = "HMAC-SHA1"; //lolwut
$postArr["oauth_version"] = "1.0";

$params = array('http'=>array('method'=>'post','content'=>http_build_query($postArr)));
$context = stream_context_create($params);
$stream = file_get_contents('https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken', false, $context);
```

I don't think my POST args are correct but ANY help is very appreciated -- I just don't want resort to use someone else's library to solve this.

-------EDIT: ATTEMPT 2 per James' input ---------

ok so here im making a call to the test link you sent me. i'm *actually* able to get a response back, but it doesnt like my signature (big surprise, i know). So just how bad did I screw up the encryption?

```
//setup GET args
$url = "http://term.ie/oauth/example/request_token.php?";
$url .= "oauth_version=1.0&";
$url .= "oauth_nonce=" . rand(0, 100000) . "&";
$url .= "oauth_timestamp=" . time() . "&";
$url .= "oauth_consumer_key=key&";
$url .= "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&";

//encrypt the request according to 'secret'
$sig = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $url, "secret")));

//append the url encoded signature as the final GET arg
$url .= "oauth_signature=" . $sig;

//do it to it
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

EDIT by James

Try:

```
//setup GET args
$url = "http://term.ie/oauth/example/request_token.php?";
$url .= "oauth_consumer_key=key&";
$url .= "oauth_nonce=" . rand(0, 100000) . "&";
$url .= "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&";
$url .= "oauth_timestamp=" . time() . "&";
$url .= "oauth_version=1.0&";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on cloud nine. Decided to revisit this problem and got it to work. Here is some very bare bones PHP to build a token request for LinkedIn (it outputs an anchor tag)

```
<?php
$endpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken";
$key = "YourAPIKey";
$secret = "YourAPISecret";
$params = array( 
    "oauth_version" => "1.0", 
    "oauth_nonce" => time(), 
    "oauth_timestamp" => time(), 
    "oauth_consumer_key" => $key, 
    "oauth_signature_method" => "HMAC-SHA1" 
);
function SortedArgumentString($inKV)
{
    uksort($inKV, 'strcmp');
    foreach ($inKV as $k => $v)
        $argument[] = $k."=".$v;
    return implode('&', $argument); 
}
$baseString = "GET&" . urlencode($endpoint) . "&" . urlencode(SortedArgumentString($params));
$params['oauth_signature'] = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $baseString, $secret."&", TRUE))); 
echo "<a href=\"" . $endpoint . "?" . SortedArgumentString($params) . "\">Get Token<a/><br/>"; 
?>
```

Comment: ok i ran into some trouble with this code at the final step where you actually make an api request. It was a bad signature, but it baffled me because it's the same routine for all steps and the other signatures worked just fine. Turns out, the api request url had a `~` character in it. Apparently, this character is **not** supposed to be url encoded in the base string!!!

When the base string is being built, **urlencode($endpoint)** should be changed to **str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($endpoint))** to help deal with this quirk.

Answer (score 1):

`oauth_consumer_key` is a value that LinkedIn should have assigned to your app. Did you register with them?
`oauth_nonce` should be different for each request to prevent replay-attacks.
If you're using HMAC-SHA1 you'll need to add the `oauth_signature` field yourself. Creating the signature manually is a total PITA.

There's also a lot of Base64 encoding to do (with the added bonus of some special OAuth quirks). I suggest you read the spec.

There is a test server and client at [this link](http://term.ie/oauth/example/index.php). It's quite useful when you're struggling to get the protocol right.

Comment: hey thanks James! Yeah I registered with them: I'll pass in the App Key. as you can cleary see I was having a hard time with what *exactly* gets passed to their API. But after reading what you said it's all making sense to me now: I'm in over my head. Now if doing this SHA1 shenanigans from scratch isn't worth it, is there another (acceptable) option for oath_signature_method? At any rate, thanks much for the link I'll put that to good use.

Comment: Yup, you can set it to PLAINTEXT instead of HMAC-SHA1, but the server may not support this for security reasons. (I've no experience of working with LinkedIn).

Comment: Ok, I tried it again, with a much better result (thanks!) I still am missing something about the process as the response back says my signature is bad. i was following the process outlined by Vimeo [http://vimeo.com/api/docs/oauth] where apparently you encrypt the entire request according to your app secret and send that along, too

Comment: Are you sorting the oauth parameters?

Comment: Just saw your edit and you're not! It's easiest to construct the param in alphabetical order. Also, 'secret' needs to have and & at the end even if you haven't got the token yet.

Comment: ah ha thanks! should i sort the arg list according to key or value? also, should it be ascending (a->z) or descending (z->a)? the order above is from 'http://term.ie/oauth/example/index.php.' In the 'Request Token' example url (using GET) they show the args in this order: Version, Nonce, Timestamp, Consumer Key, Signature Method, (Signature)

Comment: Alright sorry, my OAuth is a bit rusty. When constructing the signature the parameters have to be in ascending key order. But the final URL itself can have them in any order. That's what I meant when I said it's easiest to have them sorted all the time, it makes calculating the signature easier.

Comment: I edited your post. If that doesn't work then I'm stumped but the test server does give pretty good diagnostics. Also, the OAuth key parameters themselves also should be Base64 encoded because they may contain invalid chars, so you'll be Base64 encoding some Base64 encoding. You should be ok for now though as the Base64 encoding of your current values would be the same as the unencoded characters.

Comment: Ok I tried it with the modified secret ("secret&" instead of "secret") as well as the sorted arg list, but get the same result. I must be doing something out-of-order between the hashing, base64 encoding, and url encoding. I feel like this is where OAuth and I part company. Seriously, you take a string, run it through a canned encryption routine and send it somewhere-- I can't believe this is kicking my butt it's so embarrassing. But just the same, you really know your stuff and I have learned a lot about this whole process. thanks much!